# Algorithm for a tile based map (web browser game) like Tribal Wars world map

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, tiles, world-map

I'm trying to create a tile based world map like Tribal Wars has or The-West games.
I created a little bit of it but it loads too slow when you drag the map with your mouse.

### My algorithm works like this:

---

**On page load:**

- load the tiles from 1 to 19(x1 to y1 and x2 to y2) via JQuery's $.post method(I need the screen's width and height for that 19=1900/tile_width, because I want the map to fill the entire page)
- append the returned data(tiles) to the screen (so far so good)

---

**On map drag:**

- load again via .post tiles (based on how many pixels you dragged)
- append again the data(tiles on the screen)

---

Everything is working if you drag slow but if you want to drag like a crazy man the map will become a mess(it doesn't load all the tiles)

Can you provide me a better algorithm with some examples if possible or maybe some source codes (i didn't found nothing on google about these 2 games' maps)

P.S. I tried to put my example on 000webhost.com but I don't know why the `json_decode()` returns `null` .On my pc works fine.

Comment: Cant you use google maps engine for it, with a custom layer?

Comment: i don't think so.It's a tiled based map with specific positions of the tiles

Answer (score 0):

This is just a general idea.
I can't provide you a source code, but what you should do is quite simple:
Rather than creating, appending, clearing, re-appending every time the mouse is moved, you should create a "viewport" like code. So, all the tiles will be preset, and then at runtime, you will only print the ones that are bigger than -MAP_TILE_SIZE and smaller than screen width +MAP_TILE_SIZE on your viewport.

Comment: but what if i have 22500 of tiles? (150 by 150 map)

Comment: Is it a map, with different tiles, or is it a continuous pattern?
Either way, if you are running slow, you are either doing many actions per run, or have too many things loaded, and I think you fall into the first category.

Comment: Also, how do you render this with Javascript? Are you using a HTML5 Canvas?

Comment: Yes is the first category.But how can i improve that?It's better if i load all the map data in cache? No ,I don't use HMTL5 .It's just plain html div tags

Comment: Is it a continuous pattern, or a map of tiles, like 1 0 3 4 2 1 0 ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean but i have a div tag(#map) witch is 7000px width and height where i append tiles and when you reach the end of the map you just stop.

Comment: Alright. When you say tiles, do you mean smaller divs with backgrounds, or <img> tags?

Comment: small divs with background

Comment: Then according to what I said, you should create a div that contains the 7000px div. Let's call one div the container, and the other the map. What you should do is set CSS "position: relative;" on the container div, and "position: absolute;" on the map, and just play with the left and top values on drag. The map should be populated with the page load, or if the game is changing levels without updating the page, you should do it when the tiles are loaded.

Comment: I've done that .What I want is an algorithm which can load the tiles on drag very fast like in the-west game(check it).No matter how fast you drag the map is loading perfectly.

Comment: But in the post you say that "On map drag", you "load again via .post tiles (based on how many pixels you dragged), append again the data(tiles on the screen)". This is not what I am saying. If you append all divs within the 7000px div, and then just change the top and left css properties, it will be running as fast as the user moves the mouse, 100%.

Comment: yes it works like that but is is slow because i have to make a lot of requests and i don't know how to optimize that

Comment: Where do you need to make a lot of requests?

Comment: I made a lot of requests where i need to load the tiles from the map(the map is 150 by 150 divs), so i can't load 22000 of divs on the screen) and I make a request to the server from  where i get the needed tiles but this process takes too much time

Comment: That's why I am saying that you should probably load the 22000 divs and show only the ones you need. After all, does it sound right to you that you are using 22000 divs as the tiles of your map, anyway? There are so many other ways to do this, instead of loading thousands of elements.

Comment: 1) so you are suggesting to load in memory all 22000 divs? 2) what other ways do you know?

Comment: 1) You can try.  
2) The problem as you are describing it, on my point of view, is not when you try to load these divs, but the fact that you are using divs to create your map. If you use a HTML canvas, it will be extremely easy for you to draw all your map tiles at once and move it around - believe me, you will have a huge performance improvement.

Comment: I think i'll stay to the first option because not many people are using the latest browsers (referred to IE7 and IE8 users) and i can't use canvas tag

Comment: If you want my opinion, you should try to deliver a better experience for those aware of what "updating" means, instead of trying to maintain an over-patched code, so that your project works for everyone (which will probably result in not working for everyone anyway, because there is a huge gap between today's browsers and IE7). I have just accepted the fact that when I create something fancy, like a game or so, it has to use the latest available technology, and demand update of the browser - it won't hurt them to update those browsers (finally!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I created the map I wanted and I didn't used ajax requests for every drag event.I just loaded the entire map data in a javascript array.

This is the preview (images are not mine so I don't recommend to use them)
[image: Tile Based Map]

Here is the [REPO](https://github.com/JohnnyWolff/tmap) on github

Comment: Sorry to comment on such an old question, but do you still have the code for this?

Comment: Yes, I do. But it's not on github anymore

Comment: would you be willing to share it with me?

Comment: The map's code is linked to a game so is pretty hard to extract it as a module. The code is very old. This is the client renderer ( uses KineticJS ) http://pasted.co/783c7131 . I put a JSON example of the input data it needs . It won't help you too much(is just for you to see how I done it). Basically is just a bidimensional array. To make it work you need the images and some other tiny libs I done (which is the entire game)